# Find an orthogonal matrix for a transformation from $\Bbb R^3$ to $\Bbb R^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Find an orthogonal transformation $T$ from $\Bbb R^3$ to $\Bbb R^3$ such that:

$T\begin{pmatrix}2/3\\2/3\\1/3\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}$

I'm not sure how to start. I know that the vectors that form the columns of the transformation matrix have to be orthonormal.

Comment: Set $v=(2/3,2/3,1/3), e_3=(0,0,1)$. Since $T^tT=I$ you get $T^tT(v)=v$ ie $T^t(e_3)=v$, ie the 3rd column of $T^t$ is $v$, hence the 3rd raw of $T$ is $v$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\def\t{\theta}$
Let us put: $X=\begin{pmatrix} \frac 23  \\ \frac 23\\ \frac 13 \end{pmatrix}$ and $Y=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1 \end{pmatrix}$

You can take $T$ as the rotation transforming $X$ to $Y$ having $\Bbb R Z$  as axis where  $Z=X\wedge Y=\begin{pmatrix} \frac 23  \\ -\frac 23\\ 0\end{pmatrix}$

If $\t$ is the angle of $X$ and $Y$ in the plane $\text{Span}(X,Y)$ oriented by $Z$, you can say that the matrix of $T$ in orthonomal basis $\cal E=(\omega_1,\omega_2,\omega_3)$ where $\omega_1=Y$, $\omega_3= \frac Z{\|Z\|}$ and $\omega_2=\omega_3 \wedge \omega_1$  is :

$$R_{\t}=\begin{pmatrix}\cos \t&-\sin \t &0\\ \sin \t &\cos \t & 0 \\ 0&0& 1\end{pmatrix}$$ and compute $\theta$ using the hypothesis who says that $T(X)=Y$.

To make easy calculus you can remark that $X=T^{-1}(Y)$ and $T^{-1}$ is represented by the matrix $R_{-\t}$